# asp.net core SignalR performance - send to each client vs send to all

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I cant find any SignalR performance docs. And I dont know how to stage a 1000 users test.

My question is: **in case of 1000 clients - how different is sending to each vs to all clients performance-wise:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  hub.Clients.Client(connected[i]).SendAsync..

vs.

hub.Clients.All.SendAsync..
```

Comment: The `Clients.All.SendAsync()` is designed to send messages to all connected clients, and the `hub. Clients.Client().SendAsync()` method applies to send message to special users. They apply to different scenarios. In your scenario, if there have 1000 connected users, to send messages to them, the easiest way is using the `Clients.All.SendAsync()` method, and there is no need to find all of the connected id and then use for loop to send messages one by one. Besides, not sure which kind of performance/metrics you want to compare? You can test them on your side and check the performance.

Comment: That article is about asp.net classic, not core

Comment: Yes, you are right, the article relates the Asp.net signalR, instead of asp.net core signalr, I have deleted the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

until MS publishes SignalR perfromance article I am going to use `for` loop instead of `All`. Since my task is to make sure there is no performance penalty by sending in a loop vs All - I measured the loop and found it performing well enough. I.e. it is very fast and no point to compromise business logic to make it faster, also reading source code for `All` it does seem the loop would be faster anyway as they use `foreach`.

Measuring **sending message 1000 times to same client using `for` in a single thread shows 56ms** on Ryzen 9 3900XT.

Once the MS document is published I will re-evaluate this.